# Airport Express not getting IP address from Telus SE567 DSL router

Tags: airport, airplay, network

I'm trying to set up an Airport Express with a home network based off of a DSL wifi router (model SE567) that came with a Telus internet connection.  The Airport Express doesn't get a valid IP address from DHCP on the router.  I can plug it in with ethernet and have it work, but it's not very convenient to have to have it plugged in all the time.

What could be causing it to go to a self-assigned IP instead of getting one properly from the router?

**EDIT**: I want to use the airport express primarily for AirPlay. I want it to join my existing wifi network, which is secured with WPA2 Personal (AES).

**EDIT 2**: When I hook it up to the network via Ethernet, it works great.  I can even have it join the network and it appears to work.  The light is green, and I can play music.  But when I unplug the Ethernet cable, it stops working.  The wireless router refuses to assign a valid IP address via DHCP.

Comment: Could you give us some more details as to what you're trying to use the Airport Express for?

Comment: AirPlay. See update to the question.

Comment: Try hard resetting the AE and set up it by connecting it to your Mac via Ethernet and join the network wirelessly. This seems to work best for me.

Comment: I've tried connecting it with Ethernet, and it works until it's unplugged again.  See my second edit to the question.

Comment: Ok cool. I'm talking about connecting it only to the mac during initial set up rather than the router.

Comment: Yeah, I did that too.  After I entered the info to join the network (which I triple checked), it would restart, flash the amber light, and tell me it had no IP address.

Comment: Hmmm :S I'm sorry, I'm stuck on this one. Perhaps book a Genius bar session? It could just be incompatible with your router.